# How Do I Use PHP To Show A Unique Header IMG Based On Path On A Drupal Site?

Tags: php, drupal, header

I have a Drupal site that needs to display a unique header image based on the path. I have found some helpful code. It gets me close to where I need to be, but not all the way. I have pasted it at the end of this post.

The issue I am having is that it bases the banner image off of the characters after the first "/" after example.com in the URL. For example, example.com/forum returns a banner of header-FORUM.png.

I need it to work a little differently. I would like it to base the banner returned off the characters after the second "/" after example.com in the URL. For example, example.com/category/term should return a banner of header-TERM.png.

Any help that you can offer with this is much appreciated.

Here's the code I mentioned earlier via [AdaptiveThemes](http://adaptivethemes.com/show-a-unique-header-image-based-on-path) (FYI, there is a comment on that page that attempts to solve a similar issue to mine but I can't get it to work).

```
    <?php
// Return a file based on the URL alias, else return a default file
function unique_section_header() {
  $path = drupal_get_path_alias($_GET['q']);
  list($sections, ) = explode('/', $path, 2);
  $section = safe_string($sections);
  $filepath = path_to_theme() . '/images/sections/header-' . $section .'.png';
  if (file_exists($filepath)) {
    $output = $filepath;
  }
  else {
    $output = path_to_theme() . '/images/sections/header-default.png';
  }
  return $output;
}

//Make a string safe
function safe_string($string) {
  $string = strtolower(preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9_-]+/', '-', $string));
  return $string;
}
?>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly sure what the output of `drupal_get_path_alias` is, but try this:

```
<?php
// Return a file based on the URL alias, else return a default file
function unique_section_header() {
  $path = drupal_get_path_alias($_GET['q']);
  $pathSegments = explode('/', $path, 3);
  $section = safe_string($pathSegments[2]);
  $filepath = path_to_theme() . '/images/sections/header-' . $section .'.png';
  if (file_exists($filepath)) {
    $output = $filepath;
  }
  else {
    $output = path_to_theme() . '/images/sections/header-default.png';
  }
  return $filepath;//$output;
}

//Make a string safe
function safe_string($string) {
  $string = strtolower(preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9_-]+/', '-', $string));
  return $string;
}
```

The only changes made were to the usage of `explode`. [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) will separate the path based on the `/`, so you just need to access a different element in that array. The last parameter of `explode` is the maximum number of elements to be returned and may also need to be tweaked

Comment: Thanks Gilean! I tooked this and tweaked it slightly. I'll add it below. Works great so far!

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding an answer so I can include code. This is based on Gilean's response.

```
/** Return a file based on the URL alias, else return a default file
 */
function unique_section_header() {
  $path = drupal_get_path_alias($_GET['q']);
  $pathSegments = explode('/', $path, 3);
  $section = safe_string($pathSegments[1]);
  $filepath = path_to_theme() . '/images/sections/header-' . $section .'.png';
  if (file_exists($filepath)) {
    $output = $filepath;
  }
  else {
    $output = path_to_theme() . '/images/sections/header-default.jpg';

  }
  return $output;
}

/** Make a string safe
 */
function safe_string($string) {
  $string = strtolower(preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9_-]+/', '-', $string));
  return $string;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would do:

In your theme's template.php, create the function THEMENAME_preprocess_page (replace THEMENAME with the name of your theme) as follows. If it already exists, add the following code to that function. (disclamer: untested code)

```
function THEMENAME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  $path = drupal_get_path_alias($_GET['q']);
  $path_segments = explode('/', $path, 3);
  if ($path_segments[0] == 'category' && !empty($path_segments[1])) {
    $safe_term = strtolower(preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9_-]+/', '-', $path_segments[1]));
    $filepath = path_to_theme() . '/images/sections/header-' . $safe_term .'.png';
    if (!file_exists($filepath)) {
      $filepath = path_to_theme() . '/images/sections/header-default.png';
    }
    $variables['header_image'] = theme('image', $filepath);
  }
}
```

Using a preprocess function (like the one above) is the Drupal way to make extra variables available for a template file. You only have to add a new element to the $variables array. Once you have done the above, you can simply put the following line in your page.tpl.php:

```
<?php print $header_image; ?>
```

This will print the complete `<img>` element.

PS. Usually, I advice not to base code like this on path aliases. It's a method that breaks easily because path aliases can change.